# Jupyter hub behind kubernetes ingress

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyterhub

folks.

I used freshly installed jupyter hub behind k8s ingress controller with self-signed ssl certificate, tried to use:

```
proxy:
  https:
    enabled: true
    type: offload
```

But when I open /hub/ i got:

```
500 : Internal Server Error
[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)
```

In jupiterhub logs i can see:

```
WARNING:urllib3.connectionpool:Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /api/v1/namespaces/jupiter/pods?fieldSelector=&labelSelector=component%3Dsingleuser-server
```

And there is no explanation for how to disable SSL verify for self-signed certs.

How to disable SSL verify ?

Found description of my issue here - https://github.com/jupyterhub/zero-to-jupyterhub-k8s/issues/943

But there is no solution :/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the K8s ingress controller you can try removing the TLS secret part from it.

make it simple like

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      name: springboot-ingress
      annotations:
       ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
       ingress.kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
    spec:
      rules:
      - host: testing.mydomain.dev
        http:
         paths:
         - backend:
            serviceName: hotelapplication
            servicePort: 8080
```

remove

```
tls:
    - hosts:
        - my.website.com
      secretName: tls-secret
```

Comment: But it's not related to the ingress of k8s but to jupyter itself. I do not have tls part on ingress.

Comment: remove the TLS from the configuration.

Comment: I need to access jupyterhub via K8s Ingress with SSL enabled, but jupyter itslef must ignore self-signed cert on k8s ingress. How to do it ?

Comment: Found my issue - https://github.com/jupyterhub/zero-to-jupyterhub-k8s/issues/943

But have no idea how to fix this

Comment: Hello,

I just open-sourced a tool to manage Jupyter notebooks on Kubernetes without JupterHub and its burden, notebook-on-kube relies on existing tools/features of the Kubernetes ecosystem (Helm, RBAC, ingress-nginx, HPA, Prometheus metrics), learn more about it at https://github.com/machine424/notebook-on-kube, give it a try and let me know :)